# Access key value model in django for dynamic template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

The goal is to make texts in static templates like "about us" page dynamic with a model so that it can be edited easily later on.
My first approach was to create a static model in which I had to set a field for each data I intend to put on my templates, such as "main_page_intro" or "about_page_company_info" and so on. But a friend of mine suggested that this approach is static itself and is not right. He proposed that I create a model with only two fields, “key” and “value”. “key” to name where the text is supposed to be used (e.g. main page introduction) and “value” to write the actual text which should be displayed.
So now I have this model:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class SiteDataKeyValue(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Text place")
    value = models.TextField(verbose_name="Text")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

Now I have problems continuing this route and using this model. Suppose that I created an object in this model, with a key = "main page introduction text" and a value of = "some text here". How am I supposed to write a view for this and how should I use these key and values in my template?

P.S.: I looked up some similar questions, but couldn't understand any of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find this answer thanks to [@DanielB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766952/danielb).

My views.py:

```
class HomePageViewKVModel(ListView):
    """
    In this view we are fetching site data from database, in a function named 
    get_context_data. In this function, we filter the model for objects that 
    contains the word 'اصلی', therefore fetching data referring to the main page 
    only. After that the context list is sent to the template, and there with a 
    for loop and an if statement, each key, value set is chosen for the proper 
    place.
    """

    model = SiteDataKeyValue
    template_name: str = "core/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageViewKVModel, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["home_page_data"] = self.model.objects.filter(key__contains="اصلی")        
        return context
```