# Django needs to restart server for changing data in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

The goal is to make texts in static templates like "about us" page dynamic with a model so that it can be edited easily later on.
My model is as below:

```
class SiteData(models.Model):
    data_set_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, default="نام مجموعه داده"
    )
    main_page_english_info = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="مقدمه انگلیسی", blank=True, null=True
    )
    main_page_persian_info = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="مقدمه فارسی", blank=True, null=True
    )
```

my view is as below:

```
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = SiteData
    template_name: str = "core/index.html"

    site_data = SiteData.objects.get(pk=1)
    context_vars = {
        "site_data": site_data,
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(HomePageView.context_vars)
        return context
```

and my template:

```
<p class="mt-3 text-justified text-english fw-semibold nm-text-color"
style="direction: ltr; ">{{ site_data.main_page_english_info }}</p>
            
<p class="mt-3 text-justified nm-text-color">{{ site_data.main_page_persian_info }}</p>
```

My problem with this method is two main issues:

1. This method works and if I change data from admin panel, it will be applyed, BUT ONLY if I restarted development server! (ctrl + c and py manage.py runserver). Where is my problem? How can I solve this issue?
2. My model itself isn't so dynamic itself, and this is why I'm also trying another method which I have other problems in that, and I've asked another question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122341/access-key-value-model-in-django-for-dynamic-template)
   Now, I'll appreciate an answer to either of these question!

Comment: Note that [`runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver) is intended for use in development only, please check the docs for some [production deployment options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the `SiteData` instance when the server starts, instead of during the request. Move the query into the `get_context_data` method, E.g.

```py
class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = SiteData
    template_name: str = "core/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["site_data"] = self.model.objects.get(pk=1)
        return context
```

Original answer follows:

By default, the cached loader is used (see the loaders section [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#configuring-an-engine)), which avoids django needed to read and parse the template for every request.

I recommend leaving this enabled, and restarting as required. However, if you absolutely need this, you can change the configuration using the `TEMPLATE` variable in your settings file. You can see the available options [in the official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/api/#loader-types)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in your comment you mentioned that I have to check the docs for more info about deployment; could you please tell me that if this problem will be repeated after deployment? I mean, if I did change a data in admin panel, after deployement off course, will it be visible in the template?

Comment: By the way, why this problem occured only in this method? I did try a function base view with my other model (mentioned in my other question linked above in item 2) and I didn't have this problem. Template text changed with a simple refresh.

Comment: This behavior is independent of the deployment method - by default it will only load the template once per-process.
Previously, you likely had incidental restarts (E.g., using the dev server restarts when you edit a `.py` file, which would allow the template to reload).

Comment: I have a problem with your answer but; if what you say is related to this problem, so no template would be updatable ever! But we know this is not the case and many websites has dynamic template data which works just fine without any need to restart server.

Comment: Template data (I.e., the context) is considered for each render, I mean the templates file content itself will not be reloaded by default (E.g., `myapp/my-template.html` will only be read from disk once).

Comment: So I should have no problem then! Because I'm not changing my template, I'm just changing some context from it. Did you check my code throughly?